# Developer oriented CSS/HTML tutorial/book

Tags: html, css

I am a software developer who occasionally write CSS/HTML code. I am currently working on an application which requires a quite complicated html/css based layout and I feel that I don't understand CSS/HTML layout enough to implement it. Which books and tutorials can you recommend me to improve my skills?

P.S. I understand the difference between block and inline elements is, what floats are, etc, but what I am lacking is a coherent picture of how it works and how to layout arbitrary stuff in html/css.

P.P.S. I tried several books before and they either has a reference manual format (like this: [http://www.amazon.com/Pro-CSS-HTML-Design-Patterns/dp/1590598040](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1590598040)) or contain information which I already know, for example most of basic tutorials on w3schools, most books for dummies on amazon, etc, or even worse are designer oriented. I don't need reading about colors, etc, I just need to learn how to do layout in HTML/CSS like I do in Java/Swing or other similar frameworks.

Comment: try Lynda.com basic tutorial. I think it's a great tutorial.

Comment: I already know what it contains. I need some more low level information. Something like the book which I mentioned in the post but more readable.

Comment: Check out http://www.positioniseverything.net/ - it's a more advanced site, and they break down the little nuances in specific browsers and ways to fix them (including ways to do it without resorting to hacks). I've saved many an hour looking there for help to fix rendering issues.

Comment: Some nice tutorials about positioning and floating: http://alistapart.com/author/nstokes. Besides that, the most thorough tutorial I've encountered is http://www.sitepoint.com/web-foundations/css-layout-formatting.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Let me preface this by saying that I prefer to look up reference material online as needed (*I store my knowledge in the cloud*) rather than learning by heart an entire book on css properties that could appear to be completely out of context; at the same time I find it more beneficial to read deep into higher-level theory and guides, be it feature articles or books.

Have you been given a comprehensive styleguide or maybe even a few mockups and it's now up to you to make it into html+css? In this case I'd suggest

- [Handcrafted CSS: More Bulletproof Web Design](http://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/0321643380/ref=oh_o02_s00_i04_details) - above all, covers some of the more "hip" techniques like liquid layout and makes you comfortable with the concept of graceful degradation (meaning that IE6 and FF10 should *not* deliver the same experience). This saves you headache and heartbreaks in the long run - mine was so popular that a colleague took it overseas... for eight months
- [CSS: The Missing Manual](http://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/0596802447/ref=oh_o02_s00_i06_details) and [HTML, XHTML and CSS Bible](http://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/0470523964/ref=oh_o00_s02_i01_details) - quite in-depth and the material there is yet to be outdated. I'd suggest reading up on floats first (many quirks there regardless of previous experience) and whichever chapters would fill knowledge gaps that you feel you have, if any. Beyond that - used as reference.
- Comfortable with general concepts but need to look up an occasional property? First off, **w3schools are evil** - use [MDN](http://www.google.co.nz/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=mdn&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CDYQFjAA&url=https://developer.mozilla.org/&ei=g7NlT8_BGqXymAX1y7GgDg&usg=AFQjCNFGY2KSX7T_9FdScwRtzIdZ_YR5ZA&sig2=WvdHnxhobAUQeN-KMmJw5A) instead. Unrelated: fantastic JS reference as well as CSS/HTML that you're currently after.
- Bookmark [quirksmode](http://quirksmode.org) and [caniuse](http://caniuse.com) so that you will not be set back too far when a major browser suddenly declines to render your chiseled code correctly.
- Research frameworks that are out there. *Grid systems* would be a fantastic way to save time if the design fits; topped with jQuery-UI or [formalize](http://formalize.me) you'd have the common dreads taken care of for you (looking at you, form layouts!).

If you want to dig deeper and have better understanding of design principles and usability concepts behind a successful product, or if you are yet to come up with wireframes/page mockups etc., the reading list expands:

- [The Non-Designer's Design Book](http://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/0321534042/ref=oh_o00_s02_i00_details) - if I could upvote it a hundred times, I would. No water, easy to understand chapters, focus on design basics (contrast, repetition, alignment, proximity) that would end up contributing to a consistent, readable website (or printed media)
- You still want more? Read [Universal Principles of Design](http://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/1592535879/ref=oh_o00_s01_i00_details) - we now deviate into "general" design territory, but most ideas are transferrable.
- I'll finish the list with [Don't Make Me Think!: A Common Sense Approach to Web Usability](http://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/0321344758/ref=oh_o00_s00_i00_details) which is exactly that.

And remember stackoverflow - if you've come across an issue, somebody probably has already solved it :)

Comment: I recommend you to add this new website called SnoopCode. This is way better than w3schools or anything else out there. http://www.snoopcode.com

Comment: " w3schools are evil ", you wrote, not sloppy, not bad, not outdated, but evil, which implies a plan to harm others. What justifies your qualification of =evil=?

Answer (score 5):

I recommend reading http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/internals/howbrowserswork/.

It's not a small article. It's a very detailled, well-thought article, describing several aspects of the browser. The following may interest you:

- [Chapter 5](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/internals/howbrowserswork/#Layout) - Layout (especially the end)
- [Chapter 9](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/internals/howbrowserswork/#css) - CSS2 visual model (all parts)

Comment: Good article. There's also a related article on MDN, though I did not find its explanations as clear: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Visual_formatting_model

Answer (score 4):

If you want to know how **CSS** layout work. There a good tutorial by google

http://code.google.com/edu/submissions/html-css-javascript/

& as you said that you are know what is **CSS**. So, is better to learn how to avoid common mistakes did by beginners. there are several go articles on that. There are few :

http://sixrevisions.com/css/12-common-css-mistakes-web-developers-make/

http://webdesignledger.com/tips/the-most-common-html-and-css-mistakes-to-avoid

http://www.designdetector.com/2006/06/ten-common-css-mistakes.php

Comment: Links are dead but I'm assuming you're referring to these: http://churchm.ag/tutorial-learn-html-css-and-javascript-from-google-videos/

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest you take a look at this tutorial

- https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/courses/30-days-to-learn-html-css

It's a 30 days HTML/CSS Course of Jeffrey Way, he explains everything you need very good and in an nice way and what's the best about it, it is free (you need to register for a free account, currently at the top right corner).

Alternative:

- http://www.quackit.com/html/tutorial/
- http://www.csstutorial.net/

But there are many many many resources for learning html and css on the web.

Comment: It seems like a good introductory tutorial, but it isn't what I wanted. I need quite a low level description of browser layout algorithm.

Comment: No it is a complete low level description ! You will learn everything from the beginning. What are floats, what are inline elements and so on !

Comment: +1 to http://learncss.tutsplus.com/ ... easily the best tutorial to learn everything you need to knw. Trust me @KonstantinSolomatov , if you don't get what you want from that course, I will give you your 30 days back.

Comment: @rickyduck thank you for your respond but there was no upvote ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Anything you want to know about html/css is on [W3C](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html)

[CSS Tricks also have some good reading material](http://css-tricks.com/)

Comment: Yes, it is. But it's not very readable and very lengthy :)

Comment: I believe that in this context, the CSS (2.1) spec is more interesting than the HTML spec. Here is the link: http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/REC-CSS2-20110607 (chapters 8-11 are the most relevant to the topic at hand).

Answer (score 1):

I prefer text books. You can use postit notes to put page markers in them (any you can read them on the toilet!).

As to one for CSS - CSS The missing manual I have found quite good

HTML - The Nutshell books (that I have always found good) is a good one.

Answer (score 0):

Just go read up on how the DOM (document object model) works. Most important thing to know is that the html code is parsed from top down, and that is where your knowledge of position elements will also come in handy. Building a layout will be very easy with this in mind, and also if you keep a grid-like structure in mind. Also read up on best practices for accessibility.

I've also read some good technical articles/tutorials/etc on the [IBM developerworks](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/) site.

Everything you need is on Google, I think it's just a matter of using the right keywords :)

Comment: So DOM works quite easily, it's just an AST. The problem is in layout. Which specs do you recommend me to read? CSS+HTML specs are more than 1000 pages long, it will take me a lot of time to read, especially if I take into account how hard to read such specs are.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you want... Do you want information on how to build a HTML/CSS front-end? Or do you want to know how a browser goes about parsing HTML and CSS? If it's the former, then the most important thing is to bear in mind html is parsed top down, and then just follow grid-like structure and keep in mind how CSS adds properties to HTML elements, like positioning. Unfortunately this is going to be a visual excercise so you'll have to bear with the colors etc too :) Otherwise just look at Twitter Bootstrap CSS, 960 grid framework or HTML boilerplate and CSS reset to start

Comment: How CSS/HTML parsing works is very easy for me. What I don't understand are the rules of CSS layout engine. That what I lack in order to create components I want.

Comment: Ok give me an example, then we can better guide you to the right resources. It sounds like you're looking for technical docs although it also sounds like that's not what you're looking for.. :)

Comment: Aside from the specs, [CSS: The Definitive Guide](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596527334.do) is probably the most comprehensive resource.

Comment: So here's an example of a question that I want to be able to answer after reading the tutorial: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9735076/how-to-prevent-a-table-from-shrinking-into-a-viewport