# How to prevent a table from shrinking into a viewport

Tags: css, html-table

I have the following code:

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  padding: 0px;
  border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>B</td>
    <td>C</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>D</td>
    <td>E</td>
    <td>F</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>G</td>
    <td>H</td>
    <td>I</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

When I stretch the browser so that viewport is less than 900px, table's rows are shrinked to fit into the viewport despite the fact that I set width explicitly. How can I prevent this behavior?

Comment: Set the width on the table element.

Comment: I want the table width be equal to 900px without specifying explicitly (so I can add new column without updating the style sheet)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed to find the answer myself:

```
 td {
   padding: 0px;
   border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
   min-width: 300px;
   max-width: 300px;
   width: 300px;
   height: 100px;
   text-align: center;
   white-space: nowrap;
 }
```

Comment: This, however works in chrome only. Decided to use a different approach to the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

e: Changed Answer.

Hi,

Check this out, it will dynamically (ish) set the width of the table

http://jsfiddle.net/joshuamartin/KtAny/

```
(function() {
    var tdWidth = '300';   


    var columnCount = $("#tID").find('tr')[0].cells.length;
    var tableWidth = tdWidth * columnCount;

    $("table#tID").attr('width', tableWidth);

    // console.log(tableWidth);
})();
```

You have to manually enter the Width of your td's, because I can't figure out how you can get the CSS style from the stylesheet.

Something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/754607/can-jquery-get-all-css-styles-associated-with-an-element) might help you out if you want it all to be dynamic, but this solution seems to be working well. I've broken it down really quite a lot, but you could do it all in one line, with just a tdWidth variable.

```
(function() {
    var tdWidth = '300';     
    $("table#tID").attr('width', $("#tID").find('tr')[0].cells.length * tdWidth);
})();
​
```

Comment: Yes it solves it (actually I did it with JS) but if I add a new column, I need to change the width again which isn't the best solution.

Comment: @KonstantinSolomatov, have a look at my new response.

Comment: It's the solution that I use now (I use GWT instead of Jquery) but isn't very good IMO. 

BTW you solution has a mistake: it doesn't take a border into account

Comment: Why would it need to? You said you set the width so wanted the table to follow that. The width (in this instance) is `3 * 300`, hence 900. You didn't ask for border to be taken into account. And sure, there probably is some spectacular way to go about it, but if what works works, then why change it?

Comment: IMO, it's kind of hack. It's ok to use a hack if there's no way to workaround the problem.

Comment: Short of writing a dynamic CSS file with PHP or something, this works just fine.

Answer (score 2):

Write this `table-layout:fixed;`

```
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  table-layout:fixed;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

insert an image into each column to force the cell size;

`<img src="blank.gif" width="300" height="1" border="0" alt="">`